# Is there any replacement for "GtkRuler" in GTK3?

Tags: gtk3, rulers

I want to display the horizontal and vertical ruler on the frame with gtk3.

this is my frame:[image]

I want to display ruler on the frame like this:

[image]

BUT **GtkRuler** has been removed from GTK 3 for being unmaintained and too specialized!!

this is my GTK3/c cpde:

```
   /* The horizontal ruler goes on top. As the mouse moves across the
    * drawing area, a motion_notify_event is passed to the
    * appropriate event handler for the ruler. */
   hrule = gtk_hruler_new ();
   gtk_ruler_set_metric (GTK_RULER (hrule), GTK_PIXELS);
   gtk_ruler_set_range (GTK_RULER (hrule), 7, 13, 0, 20);
   g_signal_connect_swapped (area, "motion_notify_event",
                      G_CALLBACK (EVENT_METHOD (hrule,        motion_notify_event)),
                      hrule);
   gtk_table_attach (GTK_TABLE (table), hrule, 1, 2, 0, 1,
              GTK_EXPAND|GTK_SHRINK|GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0, 0);

   /* The vertical ruler goes on the left. As the mouse moves across
    * the drawing area, a motion_notify_event is passed to the
    * appropriate event handler for the ruler. */
   vrule = gtk_vruler_new ();
   gtk_ruler_set_metric (GTK_RULER (vrule), GTK_PIXELS);
   gtk_ruler_set_range (GTK_RULER (vrule), 0, YSIZE, 10, YSIZE );
   g_signal_connect_swapped (area, "motion_notify_event",
                      G_CALLBACK (EVENT_METHOD (vrule, motion_notify_event)),
                      vrule);
   gtk_table_attach (GTK_TABLE (table), vrule, 0, 1, 1, 2,
              GTK_FILL, GTK_EXPAND|GTK_SHRINK|GTK_FILL, 0, 0);
```

What ideas on how to solve this task would you suggest? Or on what resource on the internet can I find help?

Answer (score 0):

If your code has a compatible license, you can simply copy the GtkRuler out of GTK 2 into your code, making any changes necessary to make it work with GTK 3.

Comment: @ ptomato: GtkRuler has been removed from GTK 3 for being unmaintained and too specialized!! [link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkRuler.html#GtkRuler-struct)

Comment: Yes. But GtkRuler still exists in GTK 2. You can copy that code from GTK 2 into your application, and make it work with GTK 3.

Comment: @ ptomato: I'm new in gtk. How to make gtk2 code work with gtk3?? When I copy that code from GTK 2 into my application it show an error!!

Comment: That is too big of a topic to cover in one comment. I would suggest reading the [GTK 2 to 3 migration guide](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html) and then trying to solve those compilation errors one by one.

Comment: @ ptomato: Thank you so much. I visited it. But error don't solve. For example, "gtk_drawing_area_size" is deprecated and should not be used in newly-written code and gnome developer introduce "gtk_widget_set_size_request()" instead of it ([link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html#gtk-drawing-area-size)). But, for "gtk_hruler_new" and "gtk_vruler_new"  gnome developer don't introduce any replacement for them.

Comment: Yes, you probably have to copy gtkhruler.c and gtkvruler.c into your project as well.

Comment: @ ptomato: No, I don't copy  gtkhruler.c and gtkvruler.c into my project. I use code up and I have error in "gtk_vruler_new ()" " and "gtk_hruler_new ()".

Comment: But you have to copy gtkhruler.c and gtkvruler.c into your project, otherwise you won't have those functions.